# Why does this flatten function for a stream type give me this error?

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

```
exception Empty_list

type 'a stream = Stream of 'a * (unit -> 'a stream) | Nil

let shead s = match s with
  | Stream (a, _) -> a
  | Nil -> raise Empty_list

let stail s = match s with
  | Stream (_, s) -> s ()
  | Nil -> raise Empty_list

let sflatten ( s : 'a stream ) =
  let rec sflatten_sub (s : 'b stream) parent =
    match s with
    | Nil -> parent ()
    | Stream (child, tl) ->
       match child with
       | _ -> Stream ( shead s, fun () -> sflatten_sub (tl ()) parent )
       | Stream (_, _) ->
          sflatten_sub (shead s) (fun () -> sflatten_sub (tl ()) parent)
  in sflatten_sub s (fun () -> Nil)
```

When I feed this into the ocaml interpreter (with a `;;` on the end of course), I get this error, and I don't understand what's wrong.

```
                                          Line 21, characters 23-32:
21 |           sflatten_sub (shead s) (fun () -> sflatten_sub (tl ()) parent)
                            ^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type 'a stream
       but an expression was expected of type 'a stream stream
       The type variable 'a stream occurs inside 'a stream stream
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are your first two recursive calls to `sflatten_sub`:

```
sflatten_sub (tl ()) parent

sflatten_sub (shead s) (fun () -> ... )
```

The first parameter is going to have the same type in these two calls. Since `tl ()` returns `'a stream`, I conclude that `shead s` also returns `'a stream`. Since the head of `s` is a stream, then `s` must be a stream of streams.

In other words, it seems to me that `shead s` doesn't return the right type of value for the first parameter of `sflatten_sub`. It returns a stream element (type `'a`) but the first parameter of `sflatten_sub` should be a stream (type `'a stream`).

Comment: So, I'm trying to turn something that's a steam of streams into a single stream, of the lowest level non-stream type that's essentially a concatenation of all of the streams in an inorder traversal of the entire structure. Because, of course, it might be a stream of streams of streams, etc....

Comment: With parametric polymorphism, the behavior of a polymorphic function cannot depends on the type of its polymorphic argument. It is thus impossible (and in fact the very notion is ill-defined) to turns an `'a stream` into a `'b stream where 'b is the non-stream part of 'a`. It is possible however to define an (irregular) variant type for arbitrarily nested streams (`type 'a nested = Final of 'a stream | Nest of 'a stream nested`).

Comment: This answers my question in a way that largely just elaborates on the error and doesn't really help me solve my problem. I suppose that's a problem in how I asked the question. I really have no idea what's going on here even after this answer, or, more fundamentally, how I might fix my flatten function so I did what I was intending for it to do. So, I'm reluctant to accept it as an answer, even though, in the most technical sense, it appears to be the correct answer.